# Java pass by reference

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Why in this code i can't swap StringBuffer's?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer("One");
     StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer("Two");
     swap(a, b);
     System.out.println("a is " + a + "\nb is " + b);
 }

static void swap(StringBuffer a, StringBuffer b) {
    a.append(" more");
    b = a;
}
```

Comment: @HotLicks no insults or bashing, please...

Comment: You could, of course, make your `swap` method "work", by having it swap *the contents* of the two objects.

Comment: @Ordous - I apologize.  He clearly understands how Java works, has thoroughly researched whether Java is call by reference or call by value, and is just jerking our chains.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3579095

Comment: @HotLicks The question is clearly low quality and been discussed multiple times over. I imagine it will be closed or marked as duplicate within seconds. The user will also get his share of downvotes for both asking a silly no-effort question and the *way* he asked it. It's right to show him that (and possibly remove the ability to ask questions if this persists). But being offensive does not help at all.

Comment: @Ordous - You apparently have never seen me be offensive.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not working with the reference of the variables `a` and `b` but with `new StringBuffer("One")` and `new StringBuffer("Two")` references.

So with `b = a` you don't change `a` and `b` in main but local copies.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support pass by reference, only pass by value.  `StringBuffer a` is a reference, and this reference is passed by value.

Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void swap(StringBuffer a, StringBuffer b) {
       a.append(" more");
       b = a; // the change is local to swap(). It doesn't affect main()
}
```